# Restore audio settings - cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa

The internal speaker of my laptop never functionned under Ubuntu. I tried to follow indication on the web and now the jack audio does not work either.

The graphic interface for audio management now displays a 'dummy output' instead of the three possible outputs I used to have (one of them was working for the jack output).

In a terminal

```
alsamixer
```

raises an error:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

I did try to remove and reinstall `alsa-utils` but it did not change anything.

This happened after a failed atempt to install `alsa-driver-linuxant_1.0.23.1_all.deb` from [here](http://www.linuxant.com/alsa-driver/).

My sound card seems to be not recognised anymore. After reboot I have no more the sound icon in menu bar the upper right corner.

I think I have removed my sound card driver.
Indeed, the command `sudo lshw -class multimedia`
indicated audi device as unclaimed.

Any idea how I could revert to a better situation (that is jack support and alsa working)?

---

EDIT:
The command `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 audio` gives

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1893]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your sound card? (`lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 audio`)

Comment: This sound card is a completely different one than what the driver you installed is designed for. What guide told you to install this? It's for Conexant audio chips, not for Intel ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes! This "pre-compiled binary package" is an ugly one.

- It installs source code in `/usr/lib` rather than `/usr/src`.
- It appears to ship almost all Alsa with it.
- It compiles the kernel module from source very bluntly in a `postinst` script. So it's a source package packaged as a binary one.
- Basically it does not follow any packaging guidelines as it appears.

However, it appears to also feature some uninstall script invoked by simply removing the package (triggered by the `prerm` hook).

The driver is for Conexant hardware, but you appear not to have such a sound card!

So, long story short, just try to remove the package to revert your actions (and hope it does indeed revert all actions):

```
sudo dpkg -r alsa-driver-linuxant
```

---

Lessons for next time:

- Don't install third party packages, but if you do:

  - verify that the driver/package you're about to install is actually fit for your hardware.
  - try out changes like this on a persistent USB install for example. If it screws up or does not help, you can simply discard that installation.
- File non-working hardware as **bugs**. Hardware in Ubuntu should *just work*.
- Try to understand what you're doing - it appears that you seem not to understand what changes you made to your system.

Comment: I already removed this package (it seems it did not even properly install and caused problems with apt). Unfortunatly it did not solve the problem. I think I have to restore the drivers or something of the kind but I am a bit lost actually and does not really understand what is going on.

Comment: @AlfredM. Well, it will be hard to recover your system completely. You'll need expertise on what changes this package actually made to your system. Please, never install such untrusted third party packages again on your live system! Use a persistent USB installation to try this out which you can trash later. However, I think you can also just reinstall the current kernel package along with the alsa packages to revert the actions. It requires a lot of time and trial and error to find this all out.

Comment: By `reinstall the current kernel package`, do you mean resintall Ubuntu after saving my /home somewhere? If not could you point me towards somewhere with proper guidelines.

Comment: Just `apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.....your-version...-generic` or use a GUI package management tool. Reinstalling Ubuntu is something different.

Comment: Is it safe to do it directly or should I take some precaution? How do I know which version should I reintall? I seem to have plenty (`dpkg --list | grep linux-image` lists a lot of different versions).

Comment: Sorry, this is a totally different question. We're drifting off. You're better off using a discussion forum or the chat. I believe this is more of a step-by-step approach to repair - not really fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: I resintalled the kernel and all alsa related package and everything is now back more or less to previous state.
Internal speakers stil do not work though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem (no more alsamixer) and found this solution in a similar thread on the ubuntu forums:

This little app installs the mainline kernel for you, is super easy to use, and fixed my audio:
https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme

Source post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136303&p=12621797#post12621797

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: oh, I just saw this! the whole answer is just to install that app, and the forum post I'm linking simply links to the github page I linked. that's about as far as my knowledge goes =P